# Eigen::SparseQR fails for rectangular matrices

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have trouble getting the [Eigen::SparseQR](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseQR.html) solver to work for rectangular matrices, which should be supported.
Here is a minimum example trying to solve Ax=b:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    const Triplet<double> A_triplets[] = { { 0,0,1 },{ 1,1,1 },{ 2,1,2 } };
    const Triplet<double> b_triplets[] = { { 0,0,1 },{ 1,0,2 },{ 2,0,4 } };

    SparseMatrix<double> A(3, 2);
    SparseMatrix<double> b(3, 1);

    A.setFromTriplets(&A_triplets[0], &A_triplets[3]);
    b.setFromTriplets(&b_triplets[0], &b_triplets[3]);

    cout << "A=\n" << A.toDense() << '\n';
    cout << "b=\n" << b.toDense() << '\n';

    SparseQR<SparseMatrix<double>, COLAMDOrdering<SparseMatrix<double>::StorageIndex>> solver;
    solver.compute(A);
    SparseMatrix<double> x = solver.solve(b);
    cout << "x=\n" << x.toDense() << '\n';

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

the output of which is:

```
A=
1 0
0 1
0 2
b=
1
2
4
Assertion failed: rows == this->rows() && cols == this->cols() && "DenseBase::resize() does not actually allow to resize.", file <Eigen directory>\densebase.h, line 257
```

The `compute` call completes successfully but the `solve` does not. This does not seem to be a problem for square matrices. Additionally, using the [Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LeastSquaresConjugateGradient.html) solver instead works just fine.

I have built this using VS15 with various 3.3.x versions of Eigen, all with the same result. I also tried an older 3.2.10 for which the solver worked, but memory issues arose, e.g., `x.nonZeros()` returns 3 with elements (1,2,-6.27744e+66), although x is a 2x1 matrix.

Could someone provide insight on this?

Comment: Use dense a `VectorXd` for `b` and `x`, internally even if b is sparse, it will be converted to a dense vector before solving.

Comment: @ggael Thanks, that seems to have solved the issue all together.

Comment: @ggael I had this problem, and indeed using `toDense()` solved it. However, my right hand side is a big matrix with mostly zeroes; is there a way we can avoid exlicitely store those zeroes and avoid that `toDense()` ? Or is there some documentation that you should not use sparse right hand sides for sparse solvers ?